# Limitation on Running ComObject Word.Application Remotely

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a simple PS script to update a Word Document, and then later deploy a Signature.

Running the script on a local terminal executes okay, but attempting to execute it remotely throws the following situation.

Script will start, Launch Word (As it appears in Task Manager), however will throw error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

Piece of script below

```
$Text = "DisplayName"
$ReplaceText = "2532-35"

$Word = new-object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Open("C:\Users\testUser02\Documents\DisplayName.docx")

$Find = $Document.Content.Find
$Find.ClearFormatting()|out-null
$Find.Execute($Text, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $true, 1, $false, $ReplaceText, 2)
$Document.Save()
$Word.Quit()
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a limitation to running this remotely?

Thanks.

Comment: [1] are you running this in an interactive session? my understanding is that most ways to run code remotely runs in a _non-interactive_ session. ///// [2] has MSWord been run on that system by the account that is running the code? i _think_ the office apps _require_ that the app be run once by the account/system combo before you can use the COM interface properly.

Comment: [1] No it wouldn't be interactive. So running it locally is just starting a PS terminal and running that script. Remotely is say like, executing a PS on a remote computer on your domain. [2] MSWord has been installed and run at least once, the issue isn't starting Word, that it is able to do, as it appears in Task Manager, it's opening the Document, when doing so it has NULL value, so like it can't successfully open it.

Comment: [1] in this case "interactive session" is not "someone running the app". [*grin*] your script - when run locally - is running in an _interactive session_. you can see it right there on the screen. when run remotely, most methods give you a _non-interactive session_ ... it shows in Task Manager ... but nothing shows on the screen at all. ///// so, my question is ... are you using one of the normal remoting methods that gives a non-interactive session?

Comment: [1] Sorry Lee, my misunderstanding.I believe I am using standard methods, (I.e Invoke-Command "C:\test.ps1" -ComputerName 172.x.x.x -Credential $Credential -Verbose). That is the command I'm testing to execute the code remotely, hope that gives you some insight.

Comment: so ... i think that gives you a _non-interactive session_. have you checked that that app shows up on the target system? not just in task manager, but right on the screen for the account that you are using. i don't think that will happen. ///// where do you see the error message? what is the FULL text of the error message?